# Sodium-potassium pump (Na+/K+) time limit, endless without action potential?

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology, cell-membrane

As written in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium%E2%80%93potassium_pump#Resting_potential):

> The sodium–potassium pump mechanism moves 3 sodium ions out and moves
> 2 potassium ions in, thus, in total, removing one positive charge
> carrier from the intracellular space.

I know that thus the cell (neuron) is excitable, and due to an action potential, the ion concentrations will change since their flux is opposite as what the pump does.

But what happens if there is no action potential, and the pump tries to work forever until no sodium ions are in the cell anymore?
Presumably, this won't happen in reality but in theory then the pump could not keep the cell polarized?
Or are there other effects like leak currents that contribute, and why exactly that issue won't happen?

Comment: This won't happen, so if you want to ask about a hypothetical you're going to have to be very very precise.

Comment: Even if there is no leak or other currents there will be an equilibrium condition in which the ATP hydrolysis by the pump could drive no more ions due to the electric potential. Actually there are condition in which the pump can work in reverse, synthesizing ATP in the process.